# Removing comments from the comment box widget

Tags: facebook, comments

As the title says im a little stuck with the admin control of the comment box.

i have included the meta tag

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="[mhalpin13]" />
```

to become an administrator but it doesn't seem to be working. i can only mark comments as spam.

**Weblink**
http://www.rubb.co.uk/teamrubb.htm

This page isn't complete yet as you can see.

Any help would be great.

Thank you

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I just totally creeped on you, but it was to help you so I hope you don't mind.. In the example
`<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>`
from the [Facebook Docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/), `{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}` actually refers to your user id number. I went to facebook.com/mhalpin13, right clicked on add friend, copied the link, and pasted it below.. In it you'll see that your profile id is `51585963`, so go ahead and try that and let me know if it works. Once again, sorry for creeping.. Let me know if it works lol

https://www.facebook.com/r.php?profile_id=515859638&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fmhalpin13&friend_or_subscriber=friend

Comment: I dont mind at all... ive changed my id to the number but i still only mark them as spam. i think my code positioning is correct

Comment: I don't know if this is causing the problem, but I'm pretty sure you can't have `<div id="fb-root"></div>` inside the <head> as a matter of functional html.. And then I think the fb init script block right after it is supposed to be in the body as well.. Try moving `</head>` right after `<meta property="fb:admins" content="[51585963]" />`

Comment: And on that note, try changing `<meta property="fb:admins" content="[51585963]" />` to `<meta property="fb:admins" content="51585963" />` without the brackets..

Comment: and i meant all of `</head>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="bodytag" -->
<body onload="MM_preloadImages('images/bike/michael_halpinroll.jpg',)">`  instead of just `</head>`, my bad..

Comment: my silly mistake on that 1 but still hasnt seem to work :s.. ive moved the script tag to the start of the body and hasnt mad any difference.

Comment: are you working live on your site? and will I see all the changes you make at http://www.rubb.co.uk/teamrubb.htm?

Comment: it looks like you still need to remove `[` and `]` from `<meta property="fb:admins" content="[51585963]" />`

Comment: deleted them but still no look, it'll be something simple like that, it always is :(

Comment: well let's try getting a clean javascript console, and maybe we might fix the problem in the process.. so first of all, let's get rid of the extra comma in `<body onload="MM_preloadImages('images/bike/michael_halpinroll.jpg',)">` and let me know when it's updated.

Comment: additionally, try getting rid of `&appId=221001071261163` from `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=221001071261163";`

Comment: no luck ---------------- <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>